# Xtend Error on overriding method that is returning an ArrayList

Tags: java, eclipse, overriding, xtend

I have an interface called AbstractFactory.java.

```
public interface AbstractFactory {
    public ArrayList<TestStruct> getListOfStruct();
}
```

This interface is implemented in ExcelTester.xtend class.

```
class ExcelTester implements AbstractFactory {
 override getListOfStruct()
 {
     val a = new ArrayList<TestStruct>
     return a
 }
}
```

TestStruct is a class that contains list of variables.

```
class TestStruct
{
   @Property int iRow;
   @Property int iCol;
   @Property String sContents;
}
```

This code was able to compile but if I do a clean build, an error is thrown.
"The method getListOfStruct() : ArrayList of type
ExcelTester must override a superclass method."
In order to fix this error, I just need to "touch" the file (add space anywhere and save the file). 
I am already using the override keyword. Anyone have any idea how to make the error go away?

This should not happen during a clean build since there is no error on the code. This error only occurs if the return value of the method is an ArrayList.

Is there a limitation on using java interfaces with xtend?

Comment: How do you build your project? Can you share it somewhere?

Comment: I go to Projects -> Clean... -> Clean all projects, then I tick Start Build Immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try again with the latest nightly (2.7)? I cannot reproduce the issue with the latest version.